# 0x0 doesn't equal to nil. How do I fix the bug

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I added check for nil but the problem still exist. How do I fix the bug.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
I added some code.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnReader;
IBOutlet UILabel *_lbReader;

- (void)dealloc 
{
 [btnReader release];
 [super dealloc];
}
```

UPDATE2
I found possible problem.

```
- (void)onRotation:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 if (btnReader!= nil && _lbReader!=nil) 
 {
    _lbReader.text = btnReader.titleLabel.text;
 }     
}
```

UPDATE3
I use onRotation in my UIViewController.

Comment: The nil checks don't really matter there. If either `btnReader` or `_lbReader` *were* nil, it wouldn't cause that set fault. Your problem presumably lies elsewhere. Can you show more code?

Comment: The 'onRotation' method seems odd (is this class a view controller?) but I don't see anything wrong with the code.  Out of curiosity, have you used the static analyzer on your code yet ('Product -> Analyze' in Xcode 4)?  That might help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to know without seeing more code, but I have sometimes found that "weird" `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors can occur due to some piece of code writing to memory it shouldn't.  For example, this caused me a few hours of headache:

`NSLog(@"Error code: %i", [dict objectForKey:@"key"]);`

No, the compiler didn't warn me.  The dict was returning a NSString object but was only given space to write in a integer.  So it 'ended up' writing over some other object.  The errors were seemingly random, but if I performed certain steps precisely, I could reproduce it.  Ugh, I hated tracking that down through 20k lines of code.

So, check for stuff like this in your code.  Are you creating any low-level c object (like a c-array)?  Are you using any core-'fill-in-the-blank' (Ex: Core-Graphics, core-text, core-animation)?  These sometimes use lower level c objects/methods and if you don't use them correctly, you could be writing over another object's memory.

Finally, double check all NSString formats (like in the NSLog listed above).  Make sure all your placeholders match the objects/primitive returned to them.

There may be more to check, but that's all I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set a variable as nil, you are not guaranteed that it is nil.

If you check your break point, you might see the value is 0x020 f.ex.
When your app starts, you should set your variables to nil manually.

I keep having this issue myself.

I think this is fixed either under iOS 5 or at least if you use ARC

EDIT :

I did not see at first that these were buttons. But your check is being run before the View is ready. You have to run this function later in the queue, like under viewDidLoad as an example

Comment: Instance variables are guaranteed to be initialised to `nil`.  It's only local variables that you need to manually initialise.

Comment: Agreed, all objects are initialized to nil.  It's primitives that can have a "random" value if they're not set to anything.

Comment: the difference is between debug and release versions. In debug all iVars/local vars are instantiated to nil, in release it's not automatically, so you should do it manually. What about _lbReader  outlet you are inspecting on nil? May be the problem is with _lbReader?

Comment: @Nava, can you provide a documentation reference?

Comment: @Aaron, no, primitives are initialised to zero too.  You're confusing Objective-C with C.  Objective-C makes guarantees about initialising instance variables.  C does not.

Comment: @Nava, there is no difference with debug/release builds.

Comment: @Jim that's from experience. We had a couple of EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes in release version from a couple of variables, that were not instantiated, while in debug version same code worked seamlessly.

Comment: @Nava, that could be caused by a number of things.  [Objective-C initialises instance variables to zero.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-87015)

Comment: @Jim You're right, I've confused obj-c with C, primitives don't have random values.  But they're not all initialized to zero.  With some initial testing on some random primitives, I'm finding that `int` inits with 18028949, `CGFloat` inits to 0.000000, `NSUInteger` inits to 35728525 and `double` inits to 0.000000.  They're consistent, but not all zero.

Comment: @Aaron, I think either those are local variables not instance variables, or you're forgetting to change the string format specifiers in your logging (`%f`, `%d`, etc.).

Comment: @Jim  Huh, you're right, my examples used local declarations.  Interesting, I always initialize my iVars explicitly but I suppose I don't need to (still...it's probably a good habit anyway).  Also, I was using the console. I try to avoid using NSLog if I can use the console instead...it eliminates the possible 'headaches' of having to remove them later.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see btnReader is not nil, so you check works correctly.
It's looks like you alloc btnReader but without initialization.